# Lookup rules for callable class: A() vs A.__call__()

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I've been reading through [this excellent post](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#new-style) in an effort to better understand metaclasses, and encountered some behavior that confuses me.

**Setup**

```py
class AMeta(type):
    # Disclaimer:  this is not what a real-world metaclass __call__ should look like!
    def __call__(self, *args):
        print("AMeta.__call__, self = {}, args = {}".format(self, args))

class A(metaclass=AMeta):
    def __call__(self, *args):
        print("A.__call__, self = {}, args = {}".format(self, args))
```

**Question 1**

`A.__call__(1, 2)` prints `A.__call__, self = 1, args = (2,)`.

Args are forwarded directly (1 appears in the spot of self)
so it appears no descriptor machinery is triggered.  Based on [these lookup rules](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#class-attribute-lookup) this could be because `AMeta.__call__` is a non-data descriptor (and therefore does not
take precedence over `A.__call__`) or it could be because `__call__` is a magic method that is therefore given some special direct lookup by the interpreter.

I'm not sure which of these two hypothesis is correct, if either.
If anyone knows the answer, I'd appreciate it!

**Question 2**
`A(1, 2)` prints `AMeta.__call__, self = <class '__main__.A'>, args = (1, 2)`.

The metaclass's `__call__` gets invoked, which agrees with the [portrayal here](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#putting-it-all-together) of `AMeta`'s `__call__` being the puppet master during creation of `A` instances.

Why does the metaclass's `__call__` get invoked here?  What lookup rule is at play when I invoke `A(1, 2)` constructor-style?  Clearly `A(1, 2)` is not just syntactic sugar for `A.__call__(1, 2)`.

I've seen a number of other questions that dance around these questions but none that appear to answer them directly.

I'm using/concerned with Python 3.7+.

Comment: Having a `__call__()` method makes _instances_ of the class callable. Classes themselves are callable by default — that's how instance of them are created. The `__init__()` initializer method gets called automatically as part of that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question 1:

Although you are indeed correct that `__call__` is a magic method that is handled specially by the interpreter, that special behavior is only triggered when you say `A()` and implicitly delegate to the `__call__` method. Saying `A.__call__` executes in exactly the same way as `a.foo`, meaning that it comes down to, as you said, `AMeta.__call__` being a non-data descriptor and therefore being overwritten by the explicit definition of `A.__call__`

## Question 2:

Unlike in Question 1, the interpreter's special handling of magic methods does get invoked here. However, including metaclasses complicates things a little. The test case is roughly equivalent to the below code without metaclasses:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__call__ = self.call2
    def call2(self, *args):
        print("call2, self = {}, args = {}".format(self, args))
    def __call__(self, *args):
        print("__call__, self = {}, args = {}".format(self, args))
```

That special handling of magic methods I talked about above is that when trying to implicitly call magic methods using syntax like `A(1, 2)`, Python ignores any attributes set directly on the object, and only cares about attributes set on the type.

Thus, `A(1, 2)` is sugar for roughly `type(A).__call__(A, 1, 2)` (except for the fact that any `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` methods on the type are ignored). This explains why the `__call__` method on the metaclass gets called.

Comment: Thank you!  I NOW see that there is some material in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup that elaborates on what you said for Question 2...but the data model page is tough going (for me at least) and I rarely appreciate anything i read there until i actually encounter live consequences.